# How do I validate a text box to only allow letters and numbers using a regular expression?

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I want to validate a text box that doesn't accept any special characters using regular expressions. It just takes letters and numbers from 0 to 9. Please provide me the correct regex.

Comment: What does "2" mean in the title and the question?  Please use English, not all of us understand "2".

Comment: I mean 'to'
Thnx for correction

Comment: Nadeem, if someone told you stackoverflow is a website where you can place orders for programming tasks you can't be bothered to solve yourself, then I'm sorry but you have been misled. On the other hand, if you show us what *you've* done to solve the problem, we can help you to fix it up.

Comment: @Nadeem: A question we will answer is "is this regex correct?"  Or "What's wrong with this regex?"  Or "Why doesn't this regex do what I think it does?"  You're not asking a question we care to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

^\w+$ or ^\w*$

This matches all letters (upper and lower), numbers and underscores.

If you don't want to match underscores try:

^[a-zA-Z\d]+$ or ^[a-zA-Z\d]*$

Answer (score 7):

A regular expression would be `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` for a box that could be empty or `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` for a box that must have at least one character in it. If you have a minimum and maximum length, you can do something more like `[a-zA-Z0-9]{m,n}` where m is the minimum length and n is the maximum length and if you only had a minimum length, the regex would look more like `[a-zA-Z0-9]{m,}` where m was the minimum number of characters.

For more information, you might want to read this MSDN article on [Regular Expressions in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972966.aspx).

Comment: +1, correct, except if it's on the server side in asp.net (VB or C# at least) it wouldn't use the leading and trailing / characters.

Comment: Thomas, this assumes English alphabet only.

Comment: Yes, it does assume English alphabet. But there's no suggestion that it's not English, either.

Comment: it allows letters or numbers. The question says that should be numbers and letters (booth at the same time)