# validate special in asp.net textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please I need some help with disallowing the "-"(Minus sign) in asp.net textbox that should contain both words and numeric value using regular expression.

Please kindly assist.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Possible Duplicate? [How do I validate a text box to only allow letters and numbers using a regular expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572357/how-do-i-validate-a-text-box-to-only-allow-letters-and-numbers-using-a-regular-e)

Answer (score 0):

Check it with a custom field validator

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" id="cusCustom" controltovalidate="txtCustom" onservervalidate="cusCustom_ServerValidate" errormessage="No - (Minus sign) alowed" />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void cusCustom_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Contains("-"))
    {
        e.IsValid = false;
    }
    else
    {
        e.IsValid = true;
    }
}
```